# Warning in normalizePath("report.Rmd") : path[1]="report.Rmd": No such file or directory

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to reproduce an example form the shiny website and running into the following error. There seems to be an issue with .Rmd file. The code seems to save the report.Rmd file in temp directory but somehow it is not reading it when I try to download the plot.

Code

```
# load required packages 
library(shiny) 
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse) 


ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                  choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('regPlot')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  regFormula <- reactive({
    as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
  })
  
  output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
    plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
  })
  
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
      
      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      
      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Error

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5552
Warning in normalizePath("report.Rmd") :
  path[1]="report.Rmd": No such file or directory
Warning: Error in file.copy: file can not be copied both 'from' and 'to'
  [No stack trace available]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code confused me a fair bit to be honest with you. I changed some things to get the report to download in my tempdir() successfully so hopefully this answers your question.

```
content = function(file) {
      library(rmarkdown)
      
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      render(tempReport, switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
    }
```

Comment: I actually used the code from here - https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html. Unfortuantely, I still get the same error with your changes.

Comment: This is the error `Quitting from lines 2-1206 (report.Rmd) Warning: Error in eval: object 'b' not found [No stack trace available]`

Answer (score 0):

I had to create [report.Rmd](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/016-knitr-pdf/report.Rmd) file before running the above code. That works like a charm.